# Change Flex Button Icon Alpha using skin

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, button, icons, skin

I have a custom skin for spark buttons.

I need to control the alpha of the image i set as the button icon using the skin. i.e. I need the image to change its opacity with change in the button states.

Is there a workaround, using the skin class, rather than writing event handlers??

Answer (score 3):

When you create new button skin, you can see generated mxml markup there that sets different gradients for rects depending on states.

So, you can just set alpha values for different states in your image like

`<s:Image alpha.disabled="0.1" alpha.over="0.4" />` and so on.

**Update:**

Now I understand your problem. Icon( which is set by `icon` property) is defined and managed by code in `spark.skins.SparkButtonSkin`, and your generated skin will extend that class.

Id of control that renders icon is `iconDisplay` of type `BitmapImage`.

So, you can change its behavior by adding following code to your generated skin:

```
 <s:BitmapImage id="iconDisplay"
                   alpha.down="0.5"
                   alpha.over="0.7"
                   alpha.up="0"
                   />
```

It will not add another icon.

Comment: But in the generated skin, I couldn't find any part for the Icon. Are you suggesting to add a new icon component.